# Binary search for first occurrence in a dictionary list

Tags: python, json, binary-search

So I am dealing with large datasets, n>1000000. The data contains order information about an item. There is a boolean within the JSON formatted order called `is_buy_order`. I would like to split the list of orders into two separate lists depending if the boolean is `true` or `false`.

I have come up with an algorithm that is flawed but is faster than iteration.

The algorithm splits the dataset in half by choosing a pivot, then it checks either side to determine which side is closer to the transition point (`false` -> `true`). It continues to half until the value either side of the pivot is different or the `pivot == 1` which indicates no change.

```
start = time.time()
orders_file = open("resources/regions/"+x.replace(" ", "")[1:-1]+".json", 'r')
orders = orders_file.readlines()
orders_file.close()


item_buy, item_sell = [], []

pivot_found = False
print(len(orders))

if len(orders) > 1:
    while not pivot_found:
        temp_orders = orders
        pivot = len(temp_orders)//2

        if pivot == 1:
            break

        if json.loads(orders[pivot].replace("\n", ""))["is_buy_order"]:
            orders = orders[:pivot]
            buy_sell_index -= pivot
        else:
            orders = orders[pivot:]

        if json.loads(temp_orders[pivot].replace("\n", ""))["is_buy_order"] != json.loads(temp_orders[pivot-1].replace("\n", ""))["is_buy_order"]:
            pivot_found = True


item_buy, item_sell = temp_orders[:pivot], temp_orders[pivot:]
buy_sell_index = orders.index(item_sell[0])
print(x, time.time()-start, buy_sell_index)
```

Below is the contents of a severely reduced dataset:

```
{"duration":90,"is_buy_order":false,"issued":"2018-06-09T01:52:42Z","location_id":1027547438558,"min_volume":1,"order_id":5180297455,"price":16000.0,"range":"40","system_id":30001811,"type_id":28362,"volume_remain":892,"volume_total":892}
{"duration":90,"is_buy_order":false,"issued":"2018-06-09T01:53:11Z","location_id":1027547438558,"min_volume":1,"order_id":5180297673,"price":100000.0,"range":"40","system_id":30001811,"type_id":28366,"volume_remain":907,"volume_total":907}
{"duration":90,"is_buy_order":false,"issued":"2018-06-09T01:53:42Z","location_id":1027547438558,"min_volume":1,"order_id":5180297903,"price":100000.0,"range":"40","system_id":30001811,"type_id":21815,"volume_remain":906,"volume_total":906}
{"duration":90,"is_buy_order":true,"issued":"2018-08-03T01:50:59Z","location_id":1027954902335,"min_volume":1,"order_id":5191398100,"price":4.0,"range":"5","system_id":30001780,"type_id":34,"volume_remain":10000000,"volume_total":10000000}
{"duration":90,"is_buy_order":true,"issued":"2018-08-05T07:30:18Z","location_id":1028168079013,"min_volume":1,"order_id":5221892906,"price":2250000.0,"range":"4","system_id":30001748,"type_id":25615,"volume_remain":100,"volume_total":100}
{"duration":90,"is_buy_order":true,"issued":"2018-07-21T05:23:37Z","location_id":1022958758740,"min_volume":1,"order_id":5211030090,"price":185.0,"range":"5","system_id":30001786,"type_id":204,"volume_remain":40000,"volume_total":40000}
{"duration":90,"is_buy_order":true,"issued":"2018-08-05T07:31:23Z","location_id":1028168079013,"min_volume":1,"order_id":5221893610,"price":6000.0,"range":"4","system_id":30001748,"type_id":25616,"volume_remain":1000,"volume_total":1000}
{"duration":90,"is_buy_order":true,"issued":"2018-08-05T07:27:50Z","location_id":1028168079013,"min_volume":1,"order_id":5221891669,"price":1150000.0,"range":"4","system_id":30001748,"type_id":25619,"volume_remain":200,"volume_total":200}
{"duration":90,"is_buy_order":true,"issued":"2018-07-22T17:46:06Z","location_id":1022958758740,"min_volume":1,"order_id":5212328909,"price":12.0,"range":"5","system_id":30001786,"type_id":211,"volume_remain":1000000,"volume_total":1000000}
{"duration":30,"is_buy_order":true,"issued":"2018-07-19T22:18:58Z","location_id":1028168079013,"min_volume":1,"order_id":5210158811,"price":2000000.0,"range":"5","system_id":30001748,"type_id":16278,"volume_remain":3,"volume_total":3}
{"duration":90,"is_buy_order":true,"issued":"2018-08-05T07:32:18Z","location_id":1028168079013,"min_volume":1,"order_id":5221894118,"price":65000.0,"range":"4","system_id":30001748,"type_id":25606,"volume_remain":1000,"volume_total":1000}
```

If the dataset needs new formatting to achieve this is a possibility.

Comment: I don't really understand what your question is here.  Are you just looking for the fastest way to split the data into buy orders and others?  Or is there a spoecific problem with your algorithm that you want us to look at?

Comment: I'm looking for a fast way to split the data into an array for `is_buy_order: true` and `is_buy_order: false`, without using `for` loops

Comment: Is the data already sorted?

Comment: Yes the data is sorted false -> true

Comment: So you just want to find the point at which false turns to true? Can you extract only the relevant column (true/false)? Processing a large number of (binary/integer) values seems simpler than a whole data frame. And wouldn't averaging it give you something close to the location of the pivot?

Comment: Yes. I am unsure as to how I can extract the only column from the json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can indeed be done with a simple binary search.

```
def find_first_buy_order(data):
    """
    Performs a binary search on the passed data to find the first buy order.

    Parameters
    ----------
    data : array_like
        List of order dictionaries

    Raises
    ------
    ValueError
        When the data is unsorted, or no buy order exists in the data

    Returns
    -------
    int
        The index in data of the first buy order
    dict
        The first buy order
    """
    low = 0
    high = len(data)

    # Check boundary conditions first
    if not data or not data[-1]["is_buy_order"]:
        raise ValueError("There are no buy orders in the data set!")

    if data[0]["is_buy_order"]:
        return 0, data[0]

    while low != high:
        mid = low + (high - low) // 2

        previous = data[mid - 1]["is_buy_order"]
        current = data[mid]["is_buy_order"]

        if previous != current:     # current is True, previous is False
            return mid, data[mid]

        if previous:                # previous is True, we need to go left
            high = mid
        else:                       # need to go right
            low = mid

    raise ValueError("Are you sure the data is sorted?")
```

For your data set (I took the liberty to convert it into a list of dictionaries), I find,

```
>>>idx, value = find_first_buy_order(DATA)

>>>print(idx, value)

<<<3 {'duration': 90, 'min_volume': 1, 'system_id': 30001780, 'type_id': 34, 'location_id': 1027954902335, 'order_id': 5191398100, 'issued': '2018-08-03T01:50:59Z', 'price': 4.0, 'volume_remain': 10000000, 'range': '5', 'is_buy_order': True, 'volume_total': 10000000}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a way of doing this with the `bisect` module. By itself, it doesn't support key functions, but you can add a wrapper around your list that does:

```
from bisect import bisect

my_list = [
    {"is_buy_order": False},
    {"is_buy_order": False},
    {"is_buy_order": False},
    {"is_buy_order": False},
    {"is_buy_order": True},
    {"is_buy_order": True},
    {"is_buy_order": True},
    {"is_buy_order": True},
    {"is_buy_order": True},
    {"is_buy_order": True}
]


class KeyFuncWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, iterable, key):
        self.it = iterable
        self.key = key

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.it)

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.key(self.it[i])


# prints 4
print(bisect(
    KeyFuncWrapper(my_list, lambda x: x["is_buy_order"]),
    False,  # value for bisect to look for
))
```

This works because bisect will look at the i-th element of the `KeyFuncWrapper`, which itself looks at the application of the key function on the i-th element of your list.

Comment: Elegant - I should've come up with this!